# Instantiating classes and accessing methods from different classes

Tags: php, oop, class

I'm trying to use a Class_B function in one of Class_A's functions. But a lot of Class_B's functions include `$this` which causes problems. These are both classes (each class is of course in its own file):

```
class Class_A
{
   function hello()
   {
      require('class_b.php');
      echo 'Hello ' . Class_B::person();
   }

   function bye()
   {
      require('class_b.php');
      echo 'Bye ' . Class_B::person();
   }
}

class Class_B
{
   function person()
   {
      // various operations and variables
      echo $this->get_user($id);
   }
}
```

When I run the Class_A file I get `Call to undefined method Class_A::person() in (...)` because I think the $this value is changed when I instantiate the Class_A class. It overrules the Class_B value.  How can I stop this?

Also, another question: how can I access Class_B from every function in Class_A? I don't want to redeclare the class. Do I need to do this:

```
class Class_A
{
   function function1()
   {
      require('class_b.php');
      $class_b = new Class_B();
      // code
   }

   function function2()
   {
      require('class_b.php');
      $class_b = new Class_B();
      // code
   }
}
```

Or do I need to use a constructor or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By `Class_B::person()` you are calling the method statically. So you should declare the `person()` method as static and can't use `$this` because you don't have an instance of `Class_B`.

If you need an instance of `Class_B`, just create it and store in the `class_B` on construction.

```
class Class_A {
  private $b;
  function __construct()
  {
    $this->b = new Class_B();
  }     
  function stuff()
  {
    $this->b->person();
  }
```

Comment: This worked great. I tried to edit your post to add the final `}` but it didn't let me!

Answer (score 1):

Don't put `require` inside a method. Code in an `include`d file inherits the scope of the place where you include it, and in your example, bad things happen. Also, for class definition scripts, consider `require_once` instead of `require`, to avoid multiple definitions.

As a rule of thumb, put all `include`s and `require`s at the top of your script. Better yet, set up a class autoloader, and register it in an `auto_prepend` script. That way, you won't have to manually include anything at all (at least not for class definitions).

Comment: [Here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) is the documentation on auto-loading classes.

Answer (score 0):

What you might want is dependency injection, whereby you pass an object of `Class_B` into `Class_A`'s constructor and hold it as a property in `Class_A`. It then becomes available in `Class_A` as `$this->classB` or similar.

```
// Include Class_B code outside the class.
require_once('class_b.php');
class Class_A {
  // Property to hold Class_B
  public $b;

  // Constructor
  public function __construct($b) {
    $this->b = $b;
  }

  public function function1(){
     // code
     $this->b;
  }
  public function function2(){
     // code
     $this->b;
  }
}

// Now call your objects:
// The Class_B which will be injected into A
$b = new Class_B();
// Your Class_A, which holds an instance of Class_B as a property
$a = new A($b);
```